# LINQPad and unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, linqpad

I'm trying to crash LINQPad4 using the following C# statement:

```
new Thread(() => new Thread(() => { throw new Exception(); }).Start()).Start();
```

An unhandled exception dialog is shown, but the process doesn't die. I suppose IsTerminating = true like in all UnhandledThreadExceptions... how does it stop the process from dying?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help myself.  *Why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: Hah. Trying to add the same feature on one of my apps. :P

Comment: I knew it. Users DO try to crash programs deliberately. -)

Comment: Only when it's useful :p

Comment: Just don't try throwing a StackOverflowException - the CLR prevents you from catching this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it has a global exception handler for all non UI thread exceptions as well, something like this in the Main method:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

there are also other small things to do of course plus as usual the try/catch around the Application.Run.

see a full article and details here: [C# Tutorial - Dealing With Unhandled Exceptions](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions)

**Edit:** hb. try to debug this one: ;-)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

            new Thread(() => new Thread(() => { throw new ApplicationException("Ciao"); }).Start()).Start();

            try
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // here catching Unhandled Exceptions
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But unhandled thread exceptions always terminate the app. How is LINQPad ignoring that part?

Comment: it's not unhandled, it's unhandled inside the thread but LINQPad handles it properly.

Comment: Just making sure I'm getting this right. This works, but if I create another AppDomain, it'll crash - right? (Unless I add the handler to that AppDomain, that is.)

Comment: LINQPad's app.config includes <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" /> - this allows thread exceptions to be handled without the app subsequently dying.

Answer (score 1):

LINQPad seems to not only execute its queries, but also load its dependencies within their own AppDomain.  If you create a new AppDomain within your application, you can handle the exceptions in a friendly way and reload/compile the application in a friendly manner.

Even more interesting is how LINQPad handles its dependencies.  Apparently they are "shadow-copied" when loaded into these AppDomains, since I have a custom library that I have developed and I am able to make changes to it "on-the-fly" and LINQPad doesn't lock the file; instead, it seems as if it has a FileSystemWatcher which looks for changes to the file, unloads the AppDomain, then re-loads the AppDomain with the new dependency.

The 'pause' in the application after building a new library and then those new 'methods' that I have added are now available to scripts through intellisense indicates that LINQPad is rather intelligent when dealing with scripts and referenced libraries that: a) not only change; but b) could cause it to crash.

However, you can always use the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() if you really want to have some fun.  If you turn off optimization on your scripts in the LINQPad properties, you can actually debug into the LINQPad process, get your source code in a Visual Studio debugger window, place breakpoints, step through, examine variables, etc. in order to actually 'debug' your code snippets created in LINQPad.  It's a couple of extra lines in your script, but well worth it if you do some heavy scripting/testing within LINQPad.

This is still one of the best tools I have been able to find to prototype, unit test and build up C# code which uses LINQ queries that I can just cut & paste into applications with a relatively easy feeling they will behave as observed.